# Get Google Maps markers from the Database, to the Map

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I have a MySQL database with some lat / lng points that represent stores.  I'm going to have a map, where the user (among other things) can choose a type of store from a dropdown, and it will update the map and show only those points.  It will also show info for those points in a sidebar.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how all the code works to make this all happen.  I'm not even sure how I initially pull the MySQL lat/lng locations, and get them into javascript / jquery.

Does anyone have quick tutorials for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps [tutorial]

This is essentially a step-by-step tutorial to get you from start to finish, and written by the Google Geo Team.

Comment: this is nice, but it's not V3 compatible

Comment: @dtj Right, you are. Luckily, they have a JS V3 version of the tutorial, which is now reflected in my updated link/answer.

Comment: Ok cool!  Thanks.  Sort of a related question...I'm following the steps, but I'm doing this within Wordpress.  All my javascript code is in the theme_folder/scripts/public.js.  I have a feeling that i'm getting the path wrong for the Php script that creates the XML file.  The Php file is in theme_folder/  I've tried a few different path options, but I always get a javascript error, 'XML is Null', referring to the javascript's attempt to load the XML file...

Comment: It will be difficult to help you through the comments section alone. I suggest opening a new question relaying your issue, and the relevant code involved. It will be much easier to assist you. :)

Comment: actually i figured it out.  I set javascript variable (within my Php code) equal to the template directory, so that it's accessible in all the scripts.

Comment: @dtj Congrats! Glad you figured it out. I hope the tutorial helped.

Comment: The link in the answer is broken. The javascript part is clear and well documented on developers.google.com. But I didn't find anything on the php/mysql part anymore. Is there any new tutorial around?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution tha worked for me, I am pulling data from a database and the display them using address geocode and google maps api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      club:
      {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png' 
      },
      church:
      {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png' 
      }
    };

      function initialize() 
      {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.976178, 23.735881),
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        <?php header("content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
        $getpoints = "SELECT lat, lng, name, address, type FROM markers";

        if(!$result = $con->query($getpoints)){
        die('There was an error running the query 
        [' . $con->error . ']');
        }

        else 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $thematic = "'$row[type]'";
                $name = "'$row[name]'";
                $map_address = "$row[address]";

                $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".urlencode($map_address);
                $lat_long = get_object_vars(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));

                // pick out what we need (lat,lng)
                $lat_long = $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lat . "," . $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lng;

                echo "var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng($lat_long); 
                var icon = customIcons[$thematic] || {};
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                position: myLatlng1, 
                map: map,
                icon: icon.icon,
                title: '$map_address'
                });";           
            }
        }       

        ?>    
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: is this also used for sqlite?